# Flip animation in sub-UIView don´t found

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiview, flip, modal-view

I want flip movement in my subview.
In next method change my subview but without flip animation....

```
    int tag=g.view.tag;
    UIViewController* vc2 = [controlersOfTableBoxes objectAtIndex:tag-1];

    UIView* viewOfSelf = self.view;
    UIViewController* v = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:v.view cache:NO];

    int maxGraphs = [[viewOfSelf subviews] count];

    for (int i = 0; i < maxGraphs; i++ ) 
    {
        if([[[viewOfSelf subviews] objectAtIndex:i]  isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        {
            UIView* v = [[viewOfSelf subviews] objectAtIndex:i];
            if(v.tag==tag)
            {
                 [[[viewOfSelf subviews] objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
               break;   
            }
        }
    }
    [viewOfSelf addSubview:vc2.view];
    v.view = viewOfSelf;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

If i change this lines:

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:v.view cache:NO];
```

for

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:NO];
```

the movement is in all of screen but i want only in subview in subviewcontroller.

I try to this method:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^(void) 
     { 
         int tag=g.view.tag;
         UIViewController* vc2 = [controlersOfTableBoxes objectAtIndex:tag-1];

         UIView* viewOfSelf = self.view;
         UIViewController* v = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
         int maxGraphs = [[viewOfSelf subviews] count];

         for (int i = 0; i < maxGraphs; i++ ) 
         {
             if([[[viewOfSelf subviews] objectAtIndex:i]  isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
             {
                 UIView* view = [[viewOfSelf subviews] objectAtIndex:i];
                 if(view.tag==tag)
                 {
                     v.view=view;
                     [[[viewOfSelf subviews] objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
                     break;   
                 }
             }
         }
         [viewOfSelf addSubview:vc2.view];
         v.view = viewOfSelf;
     } 
     completion:^(BOOL finished) 
     {}];
```

but the result is the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
[UIView transitionFromView:view2 toView:view1 duration:3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom completion:NULL];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

try
 i

```
nt tag=g.view.tag;
 UIViewController* v = [controlersOfBoxes objectAtIndex:tag-1];
 UIViewController* vc2 = [controlersOfTableBoxes objectAtIndex:tag-1];
 [UIView transitionWithView:vc2.view duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^ { [v.view removeFromSuperview]; [self.view addSubview:vc2.view]; } completion:nil];
```

Comment: This solution is the same that mine... not move only subview unless move all screen

Comment: you are using UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight not UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight

Comment: is the same use UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight or UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight or UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom... the result is the same only change type of animation.

Comment: try this answer [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^(void)
{
    // Move it to wherever you want to have it.
    thisPersonViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, thisPersonViewController.view.frame.size.width, thisPersonViewController.view.frame.size.height);
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    // Do something when it completes the animation if you so desire.
}];

Comment: this works for the subview on the same view not between two different views

Comment: yes my 2 subview have the same frame, because only its necessary change one for another.

Comment: but i dont have how use correctly your solution. i have put all my code without animation code inside : [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^(void) {} but the result is the same....that before...

Comment: yes try the code i have posted as comment above i have tried it and works for me ..

Comment: ok i go to change my post with your solution, because i think that i´m doing something bad.

Comment: int tag=g.view.tag;
        UIViewController* v = [controlersOfBoxes objectAtIndex:tag-1];
        UIViewController* vc2 = [controlersOfTableBoxes objectAtIndex:tag-1];
        
        [UIView transitionWithView:vc2.view
                          duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                        animations:^
         { 
             [v.view removeFromSuperview];
             [self.view addSubview:vc2.view];
             
         } completion:nil];